# Python regular syntax remove @ string until space

Tags: python, regex

I tried to google some but it's too specific and i'm totally new to regular expression of python. May i know how can i remove the entire string after symbol @ until it next space? while this is what i do but no luck

```
s = re.sub('@[^\s]+', '',s)
```

Comment: What's the result you got? Do you want to retain the `@` symbol also?

Comment: please provide sample input and desired output for each.

Comment: @Rohit Jain, the @ removed but the string is still there

Comment: Before: @Spencerlim
After: Spencerlim

Comment: @SLim.. Please test it again. It will remove everything after and including `@` till the next space. So, `abc @cbs` will become `abc `.

Comment: @SLim please provide MULTIPLE sample input and desired output and append them to your question. not just the exact word, but the whole string you are modifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the following regex?

```
re.sub(r'@.*?(?=\s)', '', s)
```

Example:

```
>>> re.sub(r'@.*?(?=\s)', '', 'text before `at`@text-right-arter`at` text after first space')
'text before `at` text after first space'
>>>
```

It behaves exactly like your solution though (**Update:** not actually true. See the **nhahtdh**'s comment below).

Comment: @nameless: It is not the same as his solution. This case `"sjkhdfksf @kjhsjdkf"` makes your solution different from his (and other people here).

Answer (score 1):

I think it doesn't work for you because you removed '@' as well.

> i remove the entire string **after** symbol @ until it next space

try this:

```
In [1]: s='foo@barxyz trash trash'

In [2]: import re

In [3]: re.sub('(?<=@)[^\s]+','',s)
Out[3]: 'foo@ trash trash'
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you gave as input and context.

```
re.sub('@\S* ','',string)
```

See here http://codepad.org/8KmXy7aW

Comment: This will eat up everything up to and including the last space.

Comment: according to your own tests you are failing, if your input is `'test string @string test test'` your output _should_ be `'test string string test test'` not `'test string test'`

Comment: @nhahtdh fixed the answer. Inbar Rose if it should replace only the @ why not use string replace then?

Comment: @nhahtdh Fair enough but the question was 'How can I remove the entire string after symbol @ until it next space' if there is no next space it will indeed remove the entire string.

Comment: @Tuim: Well, OK. I didn't downvote you, since the question was quite confusing in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you want:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'unchanged1 @remove unchanged2'
>>> print re.sub('@\S+', '', s)
unchanged1  unchanged2
```

according to OP: 'remove the entire string after symbol @ until it next space'

to remove the extra space:

```
>>> print re.sub('@\S+ ', '', s)
unchanged1 unchanged2
```

to include the '@':

```
>>> print re.sub('@\S+ ', '@', s)
unchanged1 @ unchanged2
```